# Best way to keep an aws websocket api gateway connection alive

Tags: websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

By default the api gateway connection timeout is 10 minutes, I'd like to implement a heartbeat to keep the connection alive indefinitely. Creating a lambda scheduled in the cloudwath to every 9 minutes send a message to every connected clients should be an option, but I don't know if it is the best solution. Maybe send a ping from the client to the gateway api should be better? But in other hand the responsibility to send the pings will be in the clients, I don't know if this is a good idea.. Any idea will be appreciated.